# How to Override Extension's Plugin Class

Tags: magento2, overrides, plugin

I would like to override the Plugin class of an extension I'm using on Magento 2 as there are too many bugs in it, and I just want to rewrite the file in my module.

How can I do this?

First I tried adding this to my module's `di.xml`.

```
<type name="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Metadata\ValueProvider">
    <plugin name="Amasty_Promo::SalesRule_ValueProvider" type="Holy\AmastyPromo\Plugin\ValueProvider" />
</type>
```

But this just trow's this exception eventhough I have created the `app/code/Holy/AmastyPromo/Plugin/ValueProvide.php` file.

> Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Plugin class
>   Holy\AmastyPromo\Plugin\ValueProvider doesn't exist

Not sure what else to do, should I take a different approach?

Comment: have you create  plugin class at `app/code/ Holy/AmastyPromo/ValueProvider`,

Comment: @AmitBera, yes I have

Comment: Please share `app/code/Holy/AmastyPromo/Plugin/ValueProvide.php`

Comment: Just to understand, are you trying to override the class from Magento core, or the one from Amasty module? Also, have you considered using Object Manager Preference instead of plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Check This :

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/155527/59400

It has the solution for How to Disable or Override Plugin Class .