# How to set ifconfig for di.xml magento 2

Tags: magento2, virtualtype, di.xml, ifconfig

I want set ifconfig configuration for below code:

First code in di.xml

```
<virtualType name="searchFilterList" type="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="filters" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="attribute" xsi:type="string">KM\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute</item>
            <item name="price" xsi:type="string">KM\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Price</item>
            <item name="decimal" xsi:type="string">KM\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Decimal</item>
            <item name="category" xsi:type="string">KM\LayeredNavigation\Model\Layer\Filter\Category</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

i was tried to put ifconfig on virtualtype tag but it's not working.

Second Code in di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View">
    <plugin name="ajax_loader" type="KM\LayeredNavigation\Plugin\CategoryView" sortOrder="1" />
</type>
```

same as process above code.

can you please suggest how can i set the configuration or is there any alternative solution so please provide to me. It will helpful to me and also others.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a third party code, but I'll try to answer.
If you need to change filters type and layer type depending on configuration, then you might want to add a plugin for getFilters method of FilterList class and change layerResolver->create() statement in the action class.
As of plugin, you can replace it with your own class and call parent method or your own one depending on configuration values: [How to override or disable core Plugins in Magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155520/how-to-override-or-disable-core-plugins-in-magento2)