# Override vendor plugin Magento 2

Tags: magento2, overrides, plugin

Having some difficulty implementing this answer: [How to override or disable core Plugins in Magento2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155520/how-to-override-or-disable-core-plugins-in-magento2/155527#155527)

I have this vendor plugin I need to override the `afterToHtml` method...

Vendor DI entry:

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct">
    <plugin name="Amasty_Stockstatus::Addstatus" type="Amasty\Stockstatus\Plugin\Product\Status" />
</type>
```

Vendor plugin class:

```
namespace Amasty\Stockstatus\Plugin\Product;

class Status
{
    CODE

    public function afterToHtml(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct $subject,
    $result
    ) {
        $name = $subject->getNameInLayout();

        if ( in_array($name, array('product.info.configurable', 'product.info.simple', 'product.info.type_schedule_block6', 'product.info.bundle',  'product.info.virtual',  'product.info.downloadble')) ) {
            $status = $this->_helper->getCustomStockStatusText($subject->getProduct());
            if ($status) {
                $tmp = $this->_helper->showStockStatus($subject->getProduct(), 1, 0);
                if ($tmp != '') {
                    $result  = $tmp;
                }
            }
        }

        return  $result;
    }
}
```

My DI entry:

```
<type name="Amasty\Stockstatus\Plugin\Product\Status">
    <plugin name="Amasty_Stockstatus::Addstatus" type="Vendor\ExtensionName\Plugin\Product\Status" sortOrder="1" />
</type>
```

My plugin class:

```
namespace Vendor\ExtensionName\Plugin\Product;

class Status extends \Amasty\Stockstatus\Plugin\Product\Status
{
    public function afterToHtml(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        NEW CODE
    }
}
```

My extension is already installed and I have a class override working for a `Helper`. We are in `developer` mode. I've also tried a few other variations such as these:

1.

```
<preference for="Amasty\Stockstatus\Plugin\Product\Status" type="Vendor\ExtensionName\Plugin\Product\Status"/>
```

2.

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct">
    <plugin name="Amasty_Stockstatus::Addstatus" disabled="true" />
</type>
```

3.

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct">
```

4.

```
<plugin name="Addstatus" type="Vendor\ExtensionName\Plugin\Product\Status" sortOrder="1" />
```

5.

```
<plugin name="Vendor_ExtensionName::Addstatus" type="Vendor\ExtensionName\Plugin\Product\Status" sortOrder="1" />
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Post the method code for `ToHtml` from `Amasty\Stockstatus\Plugin\Product\Status`

Comment: @KeyurShah I've added the code to the original request.